# PHP AJAX issue with divs

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

having a few issues at the moment regarding updating the content of a div using ajax and php. I am trying to echo the price in the php script into to the div and it is not happening....maybe I'm missing something. This is a modified and simplified example of my problem.

HTML CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
function autoRefresh_div(){
    $("#tester").load("getPriceTest.php");
}
setInterval('autoRefresh_div()', 1000);
</script>

<body>

<div id="tester">3.33</div>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP CODE:

```
<?php

echo "2.22";

?>
```

Comment: The first is index.htm. The second is getPriceTest.php

Comment: Check the console for errors. Also the network tab to ensure the AJAX request is successful

Comment: `setInterval(autoRefresh_div, 1000);` pass the callback function as a parameter. not as a string.

Comment: Thanks guys, I have edited my code and neither have worked. I don't doubt your code, so I may need to check my console for errors and my network tab. This means absolutely nothing to me, but rather than getting you to explain it, could you point me to a link where I can instead learn how to do these checks. Many thanks.

Comment: Ahh, you mean the inspect element thingy to check the network. I only have access to mobile internet for a week, is their on online tool as an alternative?

Comment: Uncaught TagError: adsbygoogle.push() error: All ins elements in the DOM with class=adsbygoogle already have ads in them.

Comment: REQ: getPriceTest.php
ARG: {"0":{"totalSize":0,"position":0,"total":0,"loaded":0,"lengthComputable":false,"path":{"length":0},"cancelBubble":false,"returnValue":true,"srcElement":{"statusText":"Internal Server Error","status":500,"responseURL":"http://www.stocks.epizy.com/getPriceTest.php","response":"","responseType":"","responseXML":null,"responseText":"","upload":{"ontimeout":null,"onprogress":null,"onloadstart":null,"onloadend":null,"onload":null,"onerror":null,"onabort":null},"withCredentials":false,"readyState":4,"timeout":0,"ontimeout":null,"onprogress":null,"onlo

Answer (score 0):

Put the function in without the ', or change it to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
function autoRefresh_div(){
    $("#tester").load("getPriceTest.php");
}
setInterval(function(){
    autoRefresh_div()
}, 1000);
</script>

<body>

<div id="tester">3.33</div>

</body>
</html>
```